# c use macro Name as variable name

Tags: c++, c, macros

I have a macro defined like this:

```
#define Test_Flag  1
```

Later I want to define an element within a struct which is named the same:

```
struct adress{
    char name;
  char Test_Flag;
};

struct Adress = {0,1}
```

I already tried the following:

```
struct adress{
        char name;
      char Test_##Flag;
    };
```

Is there a way to get this Work?

Comment: No. The scope of the preprocessor is to replace each occurrence of symbol `Test5_Flag` with the specified value, that, **please note**, will **not** be `1`, but `= 1`.

Comment: You can't do this. It's very bad idea. With `#define Test_Flag = 1`, every occurence of `TestFlag` will be replaced with `= 1`. Read how the preprocessor works in your C text book.

Comment: Yes i know. This example Shows the Problem in a very simplified way. In the actual Code the Situation is slightly different.

Comment: The only solution could be `#undef Test_Flag` each time you don't want it to be replaced, but **the code will be unreadable and a complete mess IMO**.

Comment: @Loois95 you should probably [edit] your question and tell us what problem you are _actually_ trying to resolve. This looks like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @Jabberwocky  yes , i will add more Background information.

Comment: Re `#define Test_Flag = 1`: That is doubtful. Did you mean `#define Test_Flag 1`? This is also not proper C code: `struct Adress {0,1}`. Did you mean `struct adress x = {0, 1};`? Please clean up your question.

Comment: "Later I want to define an element within a struct which is named the same" The solution is to not give the same names to wildly unrelated things. Don't name all your children the same as their mother, because it will be extremely impractical and very confusing. The same goes when programming: simply refrain from doing really strange things.

Comment: @Lundin the defines are Feature switches and the Testtool I want to use accepts Feature switches as a struct. Thats why I want to Name Them the Same because in some way they are the Same. But the ones in the struct are used in the Test and Simulation eviroment

Answer (score 5):

You can use `#undef` to remove the definition of the macro:

```
#define Test_Flag 1

... Other code that uses Test_Flag.

#undef Test_Flag
struct address
{
    char name;
    char Test_Flag;
}
```

Or you can use an enumeration constant instead of a macro:

```
enum { Test_Flag = 1 };

struct address
{
    char name;
    char Test_Flag;
}
```

C has different name spaces for structure members than for other identifiers such as enumeration constants, so these will not interfere with each other.

Answer (score 1):

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67195745/4989451) works great if the macro expands into something that is compatible with `enum` that can be evaluate at compilation. Otherwise, a macro has to be reconstructed after `#undef` what is generally cumbersome and very error-prone.

I suggest using [pragma push_macro/pop_macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Push_002fPop-Macro-Pragmas.html) extension from GCC.

```
#define Test_Flag something_complicated

...

struct address
{
    char name;
#pragma push_macro("TestFlag")
#undef Test_Flag
    char Test_Flag;
#pragma pop_macro("TestFlag")
};
```

This extension is supported by major compilers including GCC, CLANG, MSC